# Examples of challenging real world examples or situations resolved using stored procedures

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Currently I'm working on gaining the different relevant skills in becoming proficient with database. Just finished reading up on stored procedures and wondering how could it apply to real world situations if any?

Hope someone could list a number of challenging real world/web problems resolved or requiring resolution by stored procedures. Any web/books/list of resources with more of such real world problems or challenging examples would be gladly welcomed too.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

- Advanced data manipulation (parsing data, unpacking binary data)
- Traversing data structured as graphs
- Abstracting away physical data model
- Security (most databases have crude mechanisms for SELECT audit)
- Flexible/extensible API design

I won't say "performance", because the typical examples in the schoolbooks are equally fast with a prepared statement.

Comment: I thought the question was of real life examples

Comment: @col, Are you saying my examples are unrealistic? They felt very real to Me when i experienced them...

Comment: These are not examples at all. Example stands for something real, off the real world experience. A practical case. "I've had some issue, decided to solve it with stored procedures, the result were ...". this site is full of theoretics who knows many right words, but almost noone ever tried it in practice.

Comment: @Col, they are all good examples of cases when using stored procedures is benificial, and I don't think you dispute that? Any specific example will be either too contrived or too complex to illustrate the point. Also, once you start analyze a single example you realize that there are more than one way of solving the problem. So what was supposed to be a show case for stored procedure turned out to be a show case for buying an ETL tool instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any batch routine, where there's lots of data to process and you don't want a lot of 'back and forth' between an application server or client application and the database.

Pretty much any secure environment when you want tight control over what goes on. You can make grants on a procedure, effectively a business process, rather than a generic grant that allows indiscriminate data updates.